# How to move stack

Tags: livecode

I am trying to move a substack up on keyboardactivated using the following code

```
local lStackLoc,lStackSize

on openstack

   set the fullscreenmode of me to "exactFit" 
   put the loc of this stack into lStackLoc
   put the effective working screenRect into lStackSize

end openstack

----------------------

on keyboardactivated

   put the effective working screenRect into tStackSize
   set itemdel to comma
   put item 4 of lStackSize - item 4 of tStackSize into tKeyboardHeight
   put item 2 of lStackLoc - tKeyboardHeight into tNewLocY
   put item 2 of lStackLoc & "," & tNewLocY into tStackLoc
   move stack "mainsub" to tStackLoc 

end keyboardactivated

----------------------

on keyboardDeactivated

   move stack "mainsub" to lStackLoc

end keyboardDeactivated
```

The stack does not move. Have I missed something, is it possible to move a substack even it part of it will be off screen?

Comment: You don't want to change the loc of the stack, but you might want to change the locations of the visible controls.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have created a group which contain all my control and I am now able to move the group. Still having some problem but I will open another question for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application running on a mobile device, or on a desktop system?

If running on mobile, stacks always display using the rect of the screen, and you can only display one stack at a time. The fullscreenMode determines how the stack is sized relative to the screen's rect and how the stack's contents are displayed, but you can't move stacks around on a mobile screen.